# How to remove whitespace - Angular 8 Databinding

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a code as follows in typescript file:

this.comments = this.comment1 + '\n' + this.comment2 + '\n' + this.comment3;

also, I have given condition if comment1 or comment2 or comment3 whichever is empty, assign it to = ' ';

In HTML I am binding it as follows:

{{comments}}

Now output is (suppose comment2 is empty string):

comment1 value

comment3 value

there is extra vertical spaces for comment2.

How can I remove the vertical space for empty comment2 string

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this:

```
getComment(comment){
    if(!comment){
      return '';
    }
    return comment ? `${comment}\n` : comment;
}

this.comments = getComment(this.comment1) + getComment(this.comment2) + getComment(this.comment3);
```

The function only applies the newline if the comment is not an empty string.

Comment: Using a function like this is only beneficial if you were to do this operation on separate comments in multiple places in your code. If you're only going to do it to create a list of comments, then Zepa's answer is best.

Comment: this worked perfectly just one thing. If all the comments are empty or null... then this.comments is binded as 0 and not empty.  It displays zero. I want to display nothing.

Comment: I edited the code to adding a conditional to handle falsy values by returning an empty string. Does this achieve what you want now?

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use array and `join`.

```js
this.comments = [this.comment1, this.comment2, this.comment3].filter(item => item != null || item !== '').join('\n');
```

#### Explanation

First. The array of 3 string values is created. Then from that array the values that are empty are filtered out. Last, all remaining elements are joined together with newline character into a string value.

Comment: I can't use array, I need it in object form only. Because later I am passing the object to a POST API. Need something that can work without changing it into an array.

Comment: What the `join` function does, its hm, "joining" all elements of that array into a single string value, but between each value it puts the newline character.

Comment: The array is created only as an intermediate element, thanks to which empty values will be filtered